# Responsive dropdown

Tags: html, css

I created a dropdown using CSS. The dropdown pops up when the elements of nav-bar are hovered. There is no error in the code. However, I need help with the styling of the nav-bar. I want all the elements in sub-menu to be in the same line, i.e, I want to elements of drop-down to be in same position while changing the information based on the element hovered in nav-bar. Reference can be drop-down on lululemon website.

```css
nav {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-list {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: .7rem;
  padding-left: 1.1rem;
}

.nav-list li {
  position: relative;
}

.nav-list>li>a {
  color: black;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 1.3rem 1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: color 300ms;
}

.sub-menu a {
  position: relative;
  top: 2rem;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-weight: 200;
  padding: 0 40px 0 40px;
}

.sub-menu {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: black;
  visibility: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50rem;
  height: 15rem;
}

.nav-list li:hover>.sub-menu {
  top: 3.85em;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="nav-list">
    <li>
      <a href="">Men</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Mens shirts</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Mens Shorts</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Mens Accessories</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="%">Women</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Womens shirts</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Womens Shorts</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Womens Accessories </a>
        </li>

      </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
nav {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-list {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: .7rem;
  padding-left: 1.1rem;
  position: relative;
}

.nav-list li {
  position: relative;
}

.nav-list>li>a {
  color: black;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 1.3rem 1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: color 300ms;
}

.sub-menu a {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-weight: 200;
  padding: 0 40px 0 40px;
}

.sub-menu {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: black;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 50rem;
  height: 15rem;
  left: 20px;
  top: 0;
}

.nav-list li:hover>.sub-menu {
  top: 3.85em;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="nav-list">
    <li>
      <a href="">Men</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Mens shirts</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Mens Shorts</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Mens Accessories</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="%">Women</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Womens shirts</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Womens Shorts</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Womens Accessories </a>
        </li>

      </ul>
</nav>
```

I made some changes to your code...basically `position: fixed` did the job. You can set the `left` value according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you needed?
The problem was that the `position:relative` was at the wrong place, it must be applied to the `.nav-list`, since its the parent of `.sub-menu` and you need it to be aligned according to it.

```
nav {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-list {
  display: flex;
  position:relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: .7rem;
  padding-left: 1.1rem;
}

.nav-list>li>a {
  color: black;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 1.3rem 1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: color 300ms;
}

.sub-menu a {
  position: relative;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-weight: 200;
  padding: 0 40px 0 40px;
}

.sub-menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  position: absolute;
  left:0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: black;
  visibility: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50rem;
  height: fit-content;
}

.nav-list li:hover >.sub-menu {
  top: 3.85em;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```